# Access element of Mootools array

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I'm using a bit of Mootools to access the values of an HTML select element but the thing is that the way to do it with Mootools [.getSelected()] returns an array and I don't know how to handle it.

my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('votconj').addEvent('click', function() {
      // This works great 
      $('jj_conjoint').addClass("validate['required']");
      $('mm_conjoint').addClass("validate['required']");
      $('aaaa_conjoint').addClass("validate['required']");
      $('conjoint_regime').addClass("validate['required']");
      new FormCheck('form');
    });
    if ($('nb_children').getSelected() == 1){
     // this doesn't work because .getSelected() returns an array and never equals 1
     $('jj_enfant1').addClass("validate['required']");
     $('mm_enfant1').addClass("validate['required']");
     $('aaaa_enfant1').addClass("validate['required']");
     new FormCheck('form');
    }
    if ($('nb_children').getSelected() == 2){
     // this doesn't work because .getSelected() returns an array and never equals 2 
     $('jj_enfant2').addClass("validate['required']");
     $('mm_enfant2').addClass("validate['required']");
     $('aaaa_enfant2').addClass("validate['required']");
     new FormCheck('form');   
    }

    new FormCheck('form');
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each` to traverse an array in MooTools:

```
var selected = $('nb_children').getSelected();

selected.each(function(element) {
  var val = element.get('value');

  $('jj_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
  //etc
}

new FormCheck('form');
```

For more info: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:each

The reason why `getSelected()` returns an array at all times, is that code like this can always be reused when you decide to add multiple selectable items instead of just one.

**Edit**

Note that the above code is directly written. Might need some tweaking to get it working for your case.

**Edit 2**

Updated code to a more comprehensive example.

Answer (score 1):

`getSelected()` returns an array because some select elements allow multiple selection. If yours doesn't, you could just try `$('nb_children').getSelected()[0]`. To get the value you can use `$('nb_children').getSelected()[0].get("value")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I've updated my post to put a more comprehensive part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the value of the selected item, right?

Try with:

```
if ($('nb_children').getSelected().get('value') == 1){//...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I've updated my post to put a more comprehensive part of my code.